# Connect facebook to post url in android

Tags: android

In my android application i would like to connect to post a url to facebook.
I tried using https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/ but am not able to cross the permission page and post the url.

I also tried using the http://www.mobisoftinfotech.com/blog/android/845/ but then i am able to see a window with title "Connect to facebook" but blank data in it.
I tried changing application key and secret kaey but of no use.

Could you please let me know why is this issue and what needs to be done to post a url to facebook.

Please share your valuable suggestions to me.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

I had some problems as well using facebook connect some time ago, so finnally I posted the urls using the "share on facebook" link directly.

Now they have changed it for the "like" button. But Ithink it is still an easy way to share contents from your application.

You can launch the browser with the "like" link to post your url.

More info:

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like